# I can't ping websites. I can ping ip address

Tags: networking, dns, ping

I can't seem to ping websites.

```
ping google.com
PING google.com(lax17s50-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4007:815::200e)) 56 data bytes
```

here I can nslookup no problem.

```
nslookup google.com                                                                 10 ⚙
Server:         192.168.228.125
Address:        192.168.228.125#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.72.174
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4007:815::200e
```

here I can ping the ip address no problem

```
ping 142.250.72.174                                                           130 ⨯ 10 ⚙
PING 142.250.72.174 (142.250.72.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 142.250.72.174: icmp_seq=1 ttl=113 time=529 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.72.174: icmp_seq=2 ttl=113 time=244 ms
```

here I can wget no problem.

```
wget google.com                                                                 1 ⨯ 10 ⚙
--2021-08-31 21:23:09--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 2607:f8b0:4007:815::200e, 142.250.72.174
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|2607:f8b0:4007:815::200e|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
```

my network interface

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces                                                         10 ⚙
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

recolv.conf

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf                                                          148 ⨯ 11 ⚙
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 192.168.228.125
nameserver 2600:100e:bf12:3b9b::92
nameserver 2600:100e:bf12:3b9b::c4
```

I can also browse websites fine.
What should I do?

I running kde and I was trying to get wireguard to work but I think I f-ed something up while doing so. Now trying to undo what I did. Any suggestions on how to get ping to work properly ? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ping command is trying to ping ipv6. Try passing the `-4` option to explicitly tell ping to ping the ipv4 address:

```
ping -4 google.com
```

In case ping is aliased to something else, try overriding the alias using the `\`:

```
\ping -4 google.com
```